# Does Package creation changes with routes in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4

Do we need to maintain separate route like web.php and api.php for routes while creating package in laravel5.4 .

I have a laravel package which is in 5.1 if i need to move in 5.4 do i need to change its route  like web and api . Currently i have it in http -> routes.php.